# XSL to remove duplicate records considering the tag and value

Tags: xslt, duplicates

I would like remove duplicates records, taking in account the tag/value.

Here is the input:

```
<Details>
    <block order="1" title="Circle A" id="Circle">
        <block id="square" title="Square 1" order="1">
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">Sun</field>
                <field order="4" title="D" id="ID d">45-34-YT</field>
                <field order="5" title="E" id="ID e">500</field>
                <field order="6" title="F" id="ID f">ABC</field>
                <field order="7" title="G" id="ID g">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="8" title="H" id="ID h">39RT</field>
                <field order="9" title="I" id="ID i">Working Closet</field>
            </block>
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">Sun</field>
                <field order="4" title="D" id="ID d">45-34-YT</field>
                <field order="5" title="E" id="ID e">500</field>
                <field order="6" title="F" id="ID f">ABC</field>
                <field order="7" title="G" id="ID g">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="8" title="H" id="ID h">39RT</field>
                <field order="9" title="I" id="ID i">Working Closet</field>
            </block>
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">Sun</field>
                <field order="4" title="D" id="ID d">45-34-YT</field>
                <field order="5" title="E" id="ID e">500</field>
                <field order="6" title="F" id="ID f">ABC</field>
                <field order="7" title="G" id="ID g">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="8" title="H" id="ID h">39RT</field>
                <field order="9" title="I" id="ID i">Working Closet</field>
            </block>            
        </block>
    </block>
</Details>
```

Here is the desire output:

```
<Details>
    <block order="1" title="Circle A" id="Circle">
        <block id="square" title="Square 1" order="1">
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">Sun</field>
                <field order="4" title="D" id="ID d">45-34-YT</field>
                <field order="5" title="E" id="ID e">500</field>
                <field order="6" title="F" id="ID f">ABC</field>
                <field order="7" title="G" id="ID g">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="8" title="H" id="ID h">39RT</field>
                <field order="9" title="I" id="ID i">Working Closet</field>
            </block>        
        </block>
    </block>
</Details>
```

I have tried with this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::node()[.=string(current())])">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but is removing these lines that i need to keep:

```
<field order="5" title="E" id="ID e">500</field>
<field order="7" title="G" id="ID g">Street xpto</field>
```

because my xslt is only considering the tag value.
I don't know how to consider the all row instead of only the value.
Can someone help?

Thanks.
Jose

More precise samples.
Example 1:
Input:

```
<Details>
    <block order="1" title="Circle A" id="Circle">
        <block id="square" title="Square 1" order="1">
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">500</field>               
            </block>
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">500</field>
            </block>
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">500</field>
            </block>            
        </block>
    </block>
</Details>
```

Output:

```
<Details>
    <block order="1" title="Circle A" id="Circle">
        <block id="square" title="Square 1" order="1">
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">500</field>               
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
</Details>
```

Result: One distinct block id "dot"

Example 2:
The 3rd Block is different because the field 2 now is "Street A"
Input:

```
<Details>
    <block order="1" title="Circle A" id="Circle">
        <block id="square" title="Square 1" order="1">
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">500</field>               
            </block>
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">500</field>
            </block>
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street A</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">500</field>
            </block>            
        </block>
    </block>
</Details>
```

Output:

```
<Details>
    <block order="1" title="Circle A" id="Circle">
        <block id="square" title="Square 1" order="1">
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street xpto</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">Sun</field>               
            </block>
            <block id="dot" title="test" order="1">
                <field order="1" title="A" id="ID a">500</field>
                <field order="2" title="B" id="ID b">Street A</field>
                <field order="3" title="C" id="ID c">Sun</field>               
            </block>        
        </block>
    </block>
</Details>
```

Result: Two distinct blocks id "dot"

I hope this new samples help clarifying what i pretend.
Thank in advance for all your replies and answers.

Comment: Is it possible that the fields differ between blocks in any way? And if so, could you give a example.

Comment: If you are limited to XSLT 1.0, then use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) instead of the inefficient method you have now. This will also allow you to use a *key* that concatenates all the values you want to consider (which ones those are is not clear from your question).

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, the fields don't differ

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I want always to have unique `<block id="dot"` contents. In this case i have 3 blocks identical, the output should be a distinct, showing only 1 block. if some value inside one of those blocks is different from the other blocks, that block should appear in the output. In conclusion, i want so use a "distinct" function to ouput unique blocks. I hope i made it a litle clear.

Comment: @JoseMartins, which XSLT processor, which version do you use or can you use? What does `unique contents` mean exactly? Would the XPath 2 and later function `deep-equal` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal express that requirement?

Comment: @martinHonnen,  i am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: That's difficult to achieve in XSLT 1. Are all the attributes of the block id="dot" and the child elements and their attributes known in advance, when writing the XSLT code?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, yes, all the attributes and child elements are known in advance

Comment: @MartinHonnen, after some checking it seems i can use XSLT 2.0

Comment: Which XSLT 2 processor exactly do you use?

Comment: For XSLT 2 blocking duplicates with `<xsl:template match="block/block/block[@id = 'dot'][some $b in preceding-sibling::block[@id = 'dot'] satisfies deep-equal(., $b)]"/>`, as already suggested in an answer, should do, even if not particularly efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you requirement might be expressable with `deep-equal` (plus the identity transformation of course):

```
<xsl:template match="block/block/block[@id = 'dot'][some $b in preceding-sibling::block[@id = 'dot'] satisfies deep-equal(., $b)]"/>
```

On the other hand, note that the approach performs poorly for larger data, the general suggestion is to use or write some fingerprint function for nodes and then group the `block/block/block[@id = 'dot']` nodes by the fingerprint value and take the first node in each group to eliminate duplicates.

A fingerprint for that known input structure might be computable as shown in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMpk/1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">

    <xsl:function name="mf:sort-attributes" as="attribute()*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="attribute()*"/>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$input">
            <xsl:sort select="namespace-uri()"/>
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:fingerprint" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="
                string-join(
                (for $att in mf:sort-attributes($element/@*)
                return
                    concat(node-name($att), '|', $att),
                for $child in $element/*
                return
                    string-join((for $att2 in mf:sort-attributes($child/@*)
                    return
                        concat(node-name($att2), '|', $att2), $child), '|')), '|')"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:key name="block" match="block[@id = 'dot']" use="mf:fingerprint(.)"/>

    <xsl:template match="block[@id = 'dot'][not(. is key('block', mf:fingerprint(.))[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope the only XSLT 3 use I have made there is the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` which should be replaced by the template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1 I hope the following use of two keys suffices:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="block" match="block[@id = 'dot']" use="concat(@title, '|', @order)"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="field" match="block[@id = 'dot']/field" use="concat(../@title, '|', ../@order, '|', @order, '|', @title, '|', @id, '|', .)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template 
    match="block[@id = 'dot'][not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('block', concat(@title, '|', @order))[1]))][not(field[generate-id() = generate-id(key('field', concat(../@title, '|', ../@order, '|', @order, '|', @title, '|', @id, '|', .))[1])])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I haven't tested that thoroughly and I am not sure if approach misses some aspects like order of child elements.

Comment: @JoseMartins, for which sample does it not work?

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDmi/2, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDmi/1 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDmi/0 seem to give the results you want for the samples shown so far.

Comment: sorry, it's working, i wrongly copy your solution.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is this might what you need?
It uses the @id of a block[field] to see if it's the only block[field] with that @id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="block[field]">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
    <xsl:if test="not( preceding-sibling::block[@id=$id])">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

10-04-2021: After the OP posted more examples, I think this should do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="block[block[field]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="block[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="block[field]">
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::block[normalize-space(.)=$fields])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="field"/> 
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::block[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks. It's almost there. But this solution don't consider changes in the values of the field tag, check please the new samples i put to this question.

Comment: @Jose Martins: Please try this updatet xslt version 1.0 again.